# H2 database IllegalStateException AssertionError 50000-200

Tags: h2

I've got a unittest that runs 11 threads in parallel at an embedded H2 database 1.4.200: 10 threads with a limited user (granted to select, insert, update) and one thread with an administrative user (=owner of the database).

The 10 user-threads just do select statements, the admin-thread runs SQL statements that could change something, but in fact not really change anything (e.g. "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XXX" for an already existing table XXX).

Sometimes this exception occurs:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "General error: ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:1ce7,len:34,liveMax:fffffffffffffd00,livePages:ffffffff,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:db,version:d9,pinCount:0 [1.4.200/3]"" [50000-200]"; SQL statement:
ROLLBACK [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.engine.Database.throwLastBackgroundException(Database.java:2221)
at org.h2.engine.Database.commit(Database.java:2202)
at org.h2.engine.Session.rollback(Session.java:846)
at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:49)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1530)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:561)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcXAConnection.getConnection(JdbcXAConnection.java:106)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:236)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
at [...]
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:1ce7,len:34,liveMax:fffffffffffffd00,livePages:ffffffff,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:db,version:d9,pinCount:0 [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$1.uncaughtException(MVTableEngine.java:93)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.handleException(MVStore.java:2877)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:481)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1338)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1312)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1272)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2780)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3290)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:1ce7,len:34,liveMax:fffffffffffffd00,livePages:ffffffff,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:db,version:d9,pinCount:0 [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:1ce7,len:34,liveMax:fffffffffffffd00,livePages:ffffffff,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:db,version:d9,pinCount:0 [1.4.200/3]
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:1ce7,len:34,liveMax:fffffffffffffd00,livePages:ffffffff,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:db,version:d9,pinCount:0
at org.h2.mvstore.Chunk.accountForRemovedPage(Chunk.java:451)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.acceptChunkOccupancyChanges(MVStore.java:1612)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1433)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1334)
... 4 common frames omitted
```

When this occurred I do not get the database back to work again (without recovery). This exception occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: GeneralError
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:352)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:333)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:301)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:74)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:192)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:189)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:352)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:384)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:234)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: chunk:d9,block:7fffffffffffffff,len:7fffffff,liveMax:0,livePages:0,map:cf,max:3c700,next:1d1b,pages:212,root:364000c7bfcf,time:1b7bf8e0,unused:1b7bfee6,unusedAtVersion:da,version:d9,pinCount:0
at org.h2.mvstore.Chunk.readBufferForPage(Chunk.java:337)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1214)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2209)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:672)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readOrCreateRootPage(MVMap.java:688)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.setRootPos(MVMap.java:682)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:576)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:535)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:516)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.LobStorageMap.init(LobStorageMap.java:87)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:791)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:307)
... 68 common frames omitted
```

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: H2 doesn't support transactional DDL anyway, so test like this has a very low meaning for H2. But if you can reproduce such weird exception with H2 compiled from current sources (it is very different from 1.4.200), you should submit a bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues because these exceptions are definitely not expected to be caused by concurrent DML and DDL operations.

Comment: OK, when there is no support for transactional DDL statements, I will have to put a lock-mechanism on top of my data access to execute exclusively either DDL or DML statements. Thanks for that hint.